# $L^p$ convergence of $f_n$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$.

Then, is it true that $\int |f_n|^p \to \int |f|^p$?

When $p=1$, the result is clearly true since $\int ||f_n|-|f|| \leq \int |f_n - f|$, but how do you show/disprove the result when $p > 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $p$-norms satisfy the triangle inequality (usually named Minkowsky's Inequality). So you can apply the same idea:
$$
\left|\,\|f_n\|_p-\|f\|_p\,\right|\leq\|f_n-f\|_p.
$$
Then $\|f_n\|_p\to\|f\|_p$, and taking the $p^{\rm th}$ power you get 
$$
\int |f_n|^p\to\int|f|^p.
$$

Comment: I do not understand your answer. how does $\int \left|\,|f_n|-|f|\,\right|^p \to 0$ show $\int |f_n|^p \to \int |f|^p$?

Comment: Sorry. It's too late and I shouldn't be posting :)

Comment: But I keep posting... Please check the edit.